# Canon reason that Ned is no longer on South Park

Tags: character, south-park

Basically, what happened to Ned? I don't remember an episode where he was killed off or anything.

Comment: It's not just Ned, this has happened to quite a few characters who were more prominent in the early series and then slowly appeared less and less.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean Ned Gerblansky, he isn't dead; at least, he was still around as recently as 2013, appearing in the episode [World War Zimmerman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Zimmerman). When Cartman went to Jimbo's store to buy a gun, Ned was there behind the counter, looking bored:

[image: screenshot from "World War Zimmerman episode" featuring Ned]

Ned, however, didn't have any lines [since 2001](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Ned_Gerblansky) (unless you count the video game [The Stick of Truth](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/South_Park:_The_Stick_of_Truth) released in March this year as canon). This sometimes happens in shows that have such a large amount of supporting characters; some are forgotten and blend into the background.

Comment: He's probably still ashamed by having that new speech box with the weird voice (Saxon in case of the German version). :)

Answer (score 4):

We can see him again in the episode [*Where My Country Gone?*](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Where_My_Country_Gone%3F) (S19E02) aired the September 23, **2015**.

[image]